# addview in list not displaying multiple records in android

Tags: android, listview

Here i have to display list like display in right but i need like left one

[image]

For that i have created custom listview and used addview() for adding policydate,paymentdate and policyamt.

Here in my **getview()** method i have used this code

```
for(int x=0;x<noofpolicy;x++){
    Log.i("Policy No",i.getpolicyno(x));
    Log.i("Payment Date",i.getpaymentdate(x));
    Log.i("Policy Amount",i.getpolicyamount(x)+"");

    LayoutInflater inflaterforpolicylist = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View hiddenInfo = inflaterforpolicylist.inflate(R.layout.rowdetaillist, null);

    TextView policynoView = (TextView) hiddenInfo.findViewById(R.id.policynooflist);
    TextView paymentdateView = (TextView) hiddenInfo.findViewById(R.id.paymentdateoflist);
    TextView policynameView = (TextView) hiddenInfo.findViewById(R.id.policyamtoflist);
    policynoView.setText(i.getpolicyno(x));
    paymentdateView.setText(i.getpaymentdate(x));
    policynameView.setText(i.getpolicyamount(x)+"");


   myLayout.addView(hiddenInfo, x, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

}
```

it showing all the record in logcat.
So here my question is that why it showing blank space in result and not displaying multiple records? What change i have to do in my code for displaying multiple records?

Comment: Why don't you use a ListView ?

Comment: Here i have used custom list for displaying data.

Comment: My guess would be that you set ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT each time you add a line. In the end, some rows may not have place to draw. Try to put ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT for the height of the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT** so that data which is not appearing to you that you can see and after that change in your xml by that it occupies full width for each record.